# "must declare the scalar variable '@x'" when binding SQL parameters

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm getting error in visual studio error is "must declare the scalar variable '@PhNo', I couldn't guess where I did misspell. I hope that will clear my bug , 
thanks in advance. :) :)

C# code:

```
string Name = Session["Username"].ToString();
con.Open();
SqlCommand Update_cmd = new SqlCommand("Update RegisterUser set FullName = @Name, PhoneNo = @PhNo ,EmailId = @ID WHERE UserName = '"+Name+"'", con);
Update_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name",txtFullName.Text);
Update_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhNo",txtPhNo.Text);
Update_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtMailID.Text);
Update_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
lblResultMsg.Text = "Your Profile has been successfully saved";
con.Close();
```

Comment: Why are you using parameters (a *good thing*!) for your `SET` part of the query, but **not** for the `WHERE` clause?!?!?!? Please use parameters **always** - otherwise, you're still open for SQL injection attacks!

Comment: whats the datatype for the phone number in table

Comment: Are you sure the most *recent/current* code is being run? Nothing looks like it should immediate cause that.

Comment: Check if `txtPhNo.Text` is `null` or not

Comment: @MikkaRin - If `txtPhNo` is a textbox, then the .Text property will not be null (but might be an empty string).

Answer (score 0):

```
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                string qry = @"UPDATE dbo.RegisterUser SET FullName = @Name, PhoneNo = @PhNo, EmailId = @EID FROM dbo.RegisterUser WHERE UserName = @Name";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtFullName.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhNo", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtPhNo.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (int)txtMailID.Text;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            };
```

You can also consider using [Prepare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbcommand.prepare%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to execute sql statements.